# Program for concatenating two vectors

Tags: r, concatenation

I need assistance in creating a program that takes a vector of strings and combines it with a vector of numbers. To produce an output of (for example) 
Apple.1, Orange.1, Peach.1, Apple.2, Orange.2, Peach.2

I currently have

```
 rep(paste(c("Apple", "Orange", "Peach"), c(1,2), sep='.') each=2)
```

But that is not working. Can anyone show me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: `paste(c("Apple","Orange","Peach"),rep(c(1,2),each=3),sep=".")`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `outer`

```
c(outer(c("Apple", "Orange", "Peach"), 1:2, FUN = paste, sep="."))
#[1] "Apple.1"  "Orange.1" "Peach.1"  "Apple.2"  "Orange.2" "Peach.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use `sapply`

```
c(sapply(c("Apple", "Orange", "Peach"), paste, 1:2, sep = '.'))
```

If you want them in the same order as akrun's solution, you can use `t`

```
c(t(sapply(c("Apple", "Orange", "Peach"), paste, 1:2, sep = '.')))
```

Which solution is quickest? `outer`

```
a <- rep(c("Apple", "Orange", "Peach"), 1000)
b <- 1:50

require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  c(t(sapply(a, paste, b, sep = '.'))),
  c(outer(a, b, FUN = paste, sep=".")),
  do.call(paste0, expand.grid(a, '.', b))
)

Unit: milliseconds
                                    expr      min       lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
    c(t(sapply(a, paste, b, sep = "."))) 76.40193 81.71269  96.04274  88.69873  98.39574 417.0988   100
  c(outer(a, b, FUN = paste, sep = ".")) 65.40994 68.89404  80.50559  75.68603  84.45135 164.9048   100
 do.call(paste0, expand.grid(a, ".", b)) 87.85504 93.79164 111.43862 104.12434 116.85417 202.7681   100
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine all combinations of two (or more) vectors, `expand.grid` is often a good starting point.

If you have your fruits in `x` and numbers in `y`, then `expand.grid(x, ".", y)` gives you the combinations you want. You just need to paste them together, so a complete solution could be:

```
do.call(paste0, expand.grid(x, ".", y))
```